# Intel Edison WiFi connection refused via browser

Tags: arduino, wifi, intel-edison

I'm using Arduino IDE with Intel Edison and upload sketch from IDE examples: *Examples -> WiFI (Edison) -> SimpleWebServerWiFi*. Just updated with password and network name. I can add code from sketch here but here is nothing special. And it seems that connection works fine:

```
Attempting to connect to Network named: L&N
SSID: L&N
IP Address: 192.168.1.102
signal strength (RSSI):-39 dBm
To see this page in action, open a browser to http://192.168.1.102
```

But when I try to open http://192.168.1.102/ in browser, result always is the same (no matter which is wifi network or which device):

```
This site can’t be reached

192.168.1.102 refused to connect.
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The avoid this issue use any other port instead of 80. Update line in code in the sketch `WiFiServer server(80);` with `WiFiServer server(81);`.

After running the sketch, url address also could be updated with the port number for web browser. For example if your IP address is `123.234.23.12` - add the `:81` at the end: `http://123.234.23.12:81`.

Comment: It means port 80 is occupied. You may run `netstat -nap -t` to see what is going on on your system.